# Showing a license/id to a shopping website, worth it?

Tags: authentication, privacy, credit-card, identity, e-commerce

I'm wondering if anyone here has ever decided to show their driver's license or ID of any sort to be able to shop at a website. I was personally asked to do this along with a facial verification. I was thinking if I were to show my driver's license, I could blur out any info I don't feel comfortable sharing such as address or DL number. I'm wondering two things currently:

1. Are there any exceptions in which someone has shown their driver's license/ID to a shopping website?
2. Would it work if I blurred out/covered info I wasn't comfortable sharing on a license/ID?

Comment: We can't share opinions here. However, this situation has come up quite a bit. Whether a blurred ID might work will depend on the retailer asking for it. My guess is 'no'.

Answer (score 0):

I have shared my ID before with third party places such as CLEAR that verify identity and have an element of video verification.

What you are describing sounds like an identity theft sort of scam, so unless the business is extremely reputable I would not do it!

Covering your details would have definitely not worked with CLEAR, but it might  work for an online retailer that only wants to verify your age. It also might not. If they are scammers it will definitely not "work" and they will demand the full scan.

Really though, this business would need to be *super* reputable.

Comment: It's not necessarily a scam. Please refer to the duplicates of the question.

Comment: Interesting, but I still probably wouldn't.